# If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator: operand type clash on index rebuild

Tags: indexing, always-encrypted, dbcc

Question: I'm using SQL Server 2016 and have a table with encrypted columns using Always Encrypt.  I had to make some changes to the table.  So, I had to drop and re-add the table.  The table has one index, the clustered index.

When I rebuild my indexes on the table specifying the name of the index it is fine:

DBCC DBREINDEX ('[case]', PK_Case_1,90);
The result is..

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Completion time: 2021-07-30T17:52:21.6183694-04:00

But, if I run it for all indexes on the table, I get...

DBCC DBREINDEX ('[case]', ' ',90);
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DBNAME') is incompatible with varchar
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Completion time: 2021-07-30T17:53:06.1301441-04:00

So, I looked to see what other indexes there may be and it only shows the one...

USE DBNAME
EXEC sp_helpindex '[Case]'

index_name  index_description, index_keys

PK_Case_1   clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY   CaseID

I ran dbcc checkdb(DBNAME,repair_allow_data_loss) - and there are no errors.

Re-ran DBREINDEX and it the result are the same.  Any ideas as to where these mixed results are coming from?

--UPDATE SOLVED--
The issue was not a hidden index, it was the statistics.  I dropped the  statistics and rebuilt the index the error no longer appears.  I'm guessing that one of the statistics was referencing an old datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild a clustered index online or offline. Here, we will discuss the steps to rebuild an index online using the SQL Server Management Studio. The detailed steps are as follows:

- In SSMS, from the Object Explorer box, click the plus sign to expand the SQL database containing the table on which you need to rebuild an index online.
- Expand the database table on which you want to rebuild the index online.
- Expand the Indexes folder, right-click the index you wish to rebuild
  online, and select Properties.
- Select Options under Select a page.
- Select Allow online DML processing, and choose True from the list,
  and then click OK.
- Right-click the index to be rebuilt online, and then select Rebuild.
- When the ‘Rebuild Indexes’ dialog box opens, make sure that the
  correct index is listed in the Indexes to rebuild the grid. Click OK.

Comment: Thank you.  Rebuilding the index was not the problem.  Although, I never did it this way.  The problem was that related to one of the table's autogenerated statistics.  The DBCCC error made it appear that the index rebuild was failing.  But, what was failing was when it tried to update one of the statics.  It would update all but one column statistics.  So, I removed it and it now shows no errors on rebuild.  But there are no statics on that column....I guess if they're needed SQL will add it automatically again.

Comment: May be you can give a try [here](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/how-to-rebuild-all-indexes-in-sql-server-database.php)

Answer (score 0):

Unless NO_INFOMSGS is specified (the table name must be specified), DBCC DBREINDEX always returns:

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Link reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-dbreindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16